# onclick event window.location.href not working on mac OS

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos

I have a button with an `onclick` event to a function that will redirect to a new page using `window.location.href`. It works as a champ, but on Mac it won't even bother doing anything; the page just refreshes itself. Here is how my code is structured:

```
<button onclick="myFunction();return false;"></button>
```

```js
function myFunction(){ 
    window.location.href = 'https://myUrl.com?var=' + value; 
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. I use Ubuntu 14.04 lts and it works very well, as on all PCs there is no problem in all browsers. It is just Mac that has got me scratching my head.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Mac? And what browser?

Comment: Same result if you remove `href`: `window.location = 'https://myUrl.com?var='+value;`

Comment: Use `type="button"` button. Browser doesn't know that you're going to abort form submission, and blocks an attempt to load a new url to the page, due to the pending submit event.

Comment: I'm using Linux and the browser is Firefox, on my laptop there is no problem and even on PCs it just fails on mac.

Comment: @DaveJuelz For a client-side problem, your development environment is irrelevant. So, you're having this problem using Firefox on Mac? What about other browsers?

Comment: yup it was on any browser in mac, but it is now resolved thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same problem.
Try using `location.href = 'https://myUrl.com?var='+value`.

Also try this: Mac isn't the problem, the problem is Safari. You need to configure this browser settings to allow open new tabs.

Comment: let me try that way. but it does not have to to open a new tab, just load a new page

Comment: it worked out, thanks! I had to loose the <button> tags and used the <input type='submit'> and it was fixed